# Concatenating two string variables in r

Tags: r, variables, dataframe, concatenation

I've seen plenty of discussion on using paste and paste0 to concatenate two strings in r.  However, this does not appear to be working for two string variables.  I have a data frame that looks like the following.

```
    series_id   year    period  value   footnote_codes
1   LASBS260000000000003            1983    M01 15.1              
2   LASBS260000000000003            1983    M02 15.0              
3   LASBS260000000000003            1983    M03 14.8              
4   LASBS260000000000003            1983    M04 14.6
```

I wish to combine the year variable to the period variable to generate a new variable in the data frame called observation. The data frame is called data and I tried the following paste command based on research of similar inquiries.

```
data$obs<-paste0(toString(data$year),toString(data$period))
data$obs<-paste(toString(data$year),toString(data$period),sep="")
```

This is not giving me the expected single variable taking on values "1983M01"... as expected.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Steve

Comment: What is it giving you instead?

Comment: Why are you using `toString`?  Have you looked at those values without calling `paste`?

Comment: Ananda, I was afraid someone would ask me that.  I'm not sure what I'm getting.  The data set is huge and when I experiment with a subset (7,000 obs), it still takes forever to process.  I seem to be getting two sets of comma delimited variables, one with years, the other with months.  I did a class(data$obs) call and it's just spinning.  Whatever, I'm getting is swamping my memory.

Comment: Richard, I'm getting character vectors from the toString statements.  The year is natively an interger, while period is a factor.  I suspect a factor would be treated as a string, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I've run into similar bizarre behavior when my columns aren't what I think they are, e.g a collaborator accidentally replaced a "column" in a data frame with a whole other data frame. Needless to say, unexpected behavior was the result

Comment: Have you also tried nesting paste calls instead of toString?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following works:

```
> apply(ddf,1 ,function(x) paste0(toString(x[2]), toString(x[3])))
[1] "1983M01" "1983M02" "1983M03" "1983M04"
> 
> apply(ddf,1 ,function(x) paste(toString(x[2]), toString(x[3])))
[1] "1983 M01" "1983 M02" "1983 M03" "1983 M04"
```

toString(ddf$year) binds entire column in one string:

```
> toString(ddf$year)
[1] "1983, 1983, 1983, 1983"
> 
> toString(ddf$period)
[1] "M01, M02, M03, M04"
> 
> paste(toString(ddf$year), toString(ddf$period))
[1] "1983, 1983, 1983, 1983 M01, M02, M03, M04"
```

Comment: @mso, paste0 is the efficient version of paste.  paste0(toString(x[2]), " ", toString(x[3]))  could give the same output as the paste line produced.

Comment: MSO, your concatenate code works, however, within the data frame, I'm still getting result like "1983, 1983, 1983 M01, M02, Mo3" using the following command.  data$obs<-apply(data,1 ,function(x) paste0(toString(x[2]), toString(x[3])))

Answer (score 7):

I encountered the problem mentioned above: I wanted to concatenate "year" (numeric) with a string variable. As a solution, I used "as.character" instead of "toString" and then concatenated the variables using "paste0". This worked for me. For example,

`df$c<-paste0(as.character(df$a)," ", as.character(df$b))`

I know this is an old post. Hoping this helps some other users in a similar situation.

Comment: Your `as.character`s are unnecessary, e.g., `paste0(1:3, c("a", "b", "c"))` works just fine.

Comment: Also, the point of `paste0` is that it's a quick way to *not* insert a space. Inserting the space is the default of `paste()`, so if you want spaces separating your terms you can just `paste(1:3, c("a", "b", "c"))` and let the default work. Or in your case `df$c <- paste(df$a, df$b)`.