# Concatenating two string variables in dataframe in R

Tags: r, variables, dataframe, concatenation

My question has been asked previously in the following link. However, if you read Steven Miller's comment tagged on the Answer, he is still having problems with the code (because in the dataframe I do not get the concatenated pattern I want). I also have the same issue. How can I fix this problem?

[Concatenating two string variables in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26321702/concatenating-two-string-variables-in-r)

For instance, I have a data frame that looks like this

```
bankname    bankid  year   quarter totass  cash    bond    loans 
Bank A      1       1881    1 244789  7250    20218   29513 
Bank B      2       1881    3 195755  10243   185151  2800 
Bank C      3       1881    2 107736  13357   177612  NA 
Bank D      4       1881    4 170600  35000   20000   5000 
Bank E      5       1881    3 3200000 351266  314012  NA
```

This is the code to create this dataframe

```
bankid <- c( 1, 2,  3,  4,  5)
year<- c( 1881, 1881,   1881,   1881,   1881)
quarter<-c(3,1,1,2,4)
totass  <- c(244789,    195755, 107736, 170600, 32000000)
cash<-c(7250,10243,13357,35000,351266)
bond<-c(20218,185151,177612,20000,314012)
loans<-c(29513,2800,NA,5000,NA)
bankdata<-data.frame(bankid,year,quarter, totass, cash, bond, loans)
```

If you use the code suggested in the link
[Concatenating two string variables in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26321702/concatenating-two-string-variables-in-r)

```
bankdata$yearquarter <-apply (bankdata,1,function(x) paste0(toString(year),toString(quarter)))
```

you still get this in the dataframe.

```
bankdata$yq
# [1] "1881, 1881, 1881, 1881, 18813, 1, 1, 2, 4"
```

How do you solve this problem?

```
> sessionInfo()

R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.2

    > conflicts()

[1] "body<-"    "kronecker"
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenating two string variables in r](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26321702/concatenating-two-string-variables-in-r)

Comment: Wait until the other question receive an answer, double asking is not permitted/encouraged if it is not totally answered post here your other doubts with complete information. What did you tried btw?

Comment: @Llopis I said in my question that I am waiting for people to respond to Steven Miller's unanswered question posted 6 months ago. I do not see people responding to it anytime soon unless I ask again. If you read his comment, he says it does not work in his dataframe. I have the same problem and want to know why.

Comment: There's no reason why `with(bankdata, paste(year, quarter))` shouldn't work here. If it doesn't, then there's something else going on in your environment. Show the output of `sessionInfo()` so we can see what other packages are loaded and also show `conflicts()` to see if you've replaced a standard function. Also, be sure to verify that your example is reproducible.

Comment: @MrFlick It works for someone else (plafort), but not for me. I added sessionInfo() and conflickts() reults in the question box.

Comment: @MrFlick The code works if I do not change these values to string values. However, as soon as you use toString, it does not work.

Comment: None of your examples use `toString()`. You're not using this, are you?

Comment: Well, don't use `toString()`! That does not do what you want. You may want `as.character()` but as you can see from our working examples, it's not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help if you provided more information. Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(x=1:26, y=as.factor(LETTERS))
paste(df$x, df$y)
[1] "1 A"  "2 B"  "3 C"  "4 D"  "5 E"...
paste(df$x, df$y, sep="")
[1] "1A"  "2B"  "3C"  "4D"  "5E"...
```

It doesn't matter what class the elements are, the engine will convert them to character class.

If this does not solve it, include a sample of your data to get more help.

Comment: I edited my question. It will be helpful if you can solve this problem. Thanks!

Comment: paste(bankdata$year, bankdata$quarter, sep=":") Or you can choose whatever separator you want. You do not need to use 'apply' as R executes vectorized operations well.

Comment: you still get [1] "1881, 1881, 1881, 1881, 1881:3, 1, 1, 2, 4".. :(

Comment: > paste(bankdata$year, bankdata$quarter, sep=":")
    [1] "1881:3" "1881:1" "1881:1" "1881:2" "1881:4"

Comment: My output is fine using the data you provided. You might have system differences that are making trouble. What R version, RStudio, operating system, and cpu brand are you using?

Comment: I am using R version 3.1.2. R studio version 0.98.1102, Window, and Intel.

Comment: what output do you get from this code: paste(1:2, 3:4)

Comment: test<-paste(1:2, 3:4)...[1] "1 3" "2 4"

Comment: that's good. what about paste(c(1881, 1881), c(3,1)). Because those are the first two elements of your desired output.

Comment: [1] "1881 3" "1881 1"...It works when I do not change these values to string values. I think conflicts come from toString function.

Comment: paste(bankdata$year, bankdata$quarter)

Comment: that's all you need. No tostring function necessary.